# Center items and align text left on mobiles using flex?

Tags: html, wordpress, css, flexbox

I'm trying to center the columns on devices under 652px using flex.

I managed to center using webkit (although i cant get it to work on internet explorer) but i'd also like the text to be central and left aligned. I made a fiddle with my issue.

```
 .row {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
}
    /** On desktops, we'll align the elements in a row using flexbox **/
    @media (min-width: 652px) {
    .flex-item-top-footer {
    flex: 33.33% !important;
    text-align: -moz-center !important;
    text-align: -webkit-center !important;
    }
}

    @media (max-width: 651px)  {
    .flex-item-top-footer  {
    text-align: -moz-center !important;
    text-align: -webkit-center !important;
    flex: 100% !important;
}
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7a731k92/1/

Any ideas?

Comment: Prefixed `text-align` were dropped about 8-15 years ago ... https://jsfiddle.net/7a731k92/2/

Comment: Hi, but how can i have it centred but the text left align, while it is all still central. I'm thinking its not possible.

Comment: As you didn't on any of your questions, are you aware of that you are suppose to accept the answer that help you the most/solved the question you asked? ... Simply click the gray check mark on the left hand side of the answer, which any user can do no matter what reputation points they have

Comment: If you check the dupe's answer's last sample, it use `inline-flex` to solve the centering of flex column items.